# Unity with NServiceBus

Tags: unity-container, ioc-container, nservicebus

How to use NServiceBus 2.6 with Unity 2.1. Is it possible? When I downloaded from NuGet NServiceBus-Unity (which is for Unity 1.2) module I got exception in AddPolicies (AutowireEnabledInjectionProperty.cs) because of typeToCreate is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check this out : http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/9196 ?

And Szymon answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5455970/261950